# select distinct values in multiple column and save in common column with column tags

Tags: postgresql, distinct

I have a table in postgres with two columns:

```
col1    col2
a       a
b       c
d       e
f       f
```

I would like to have distinct on the two columns and make one column and later assign the tag of column name from where it is coming. The desired output is:

```
col   source
a     col1, col2
b     col1
c     col1
d     col1
e     col1
f     col1, col2
```

I am able to find distinct in individual columns but not able to make a single column and add label source.

below is the query i am using:

```
select distinct on (col1, col2) col1, col2 from table
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can un-pivot the columns and the aggregate them back:

```
select u.value, string_agg(distinct u.source, ',' order by u.source)
from data
  cross join lateral (  
     values('col1', col1), ('col2', col2)
  )as u(source,value)
group by u.value
order by u.value;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=45c44778ecaff99ffc1da1ea8bd18616)

Alternatively, if you don't want to list each column, you can convert the row to a JSON value and then un-pivot that:

```
select x.value, string_agg(distinct x.source, ',' order by x.source)
from data d
  cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(d)) as x(source, value)
group by x.value  
order by x.value;
```